Rust's ash crate 'Unable to load create_wayland_surface_khr'
I'm trying to create a SurfaceKHR with create_wayland_surface using the following line of code
let surface_khr: vk::SurfaceKHR = unsafe{wayland_display_instance.create_wayland_surface(&wayland_display_surface_create_info,None)}.expect("failed to create display surface");

when ran, I get the error:
thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to load create_wayland_surface_khr', /home/lazerpie/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/ash-0.38.0+1.3.281/src/extensions_generated.rs:10495:29
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

when ran with RUST_BACKTRACE=1
thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to load create_wayland_surface_khr', /home/lazerpie/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/ash-0.38.0+1.3.281/src/extensions_generated.rs:10495:29
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/5680fa18feaa87f3ff04063800aec256c3d4b4be/library/std/src/panicking.rs:593:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/5680fa18feaa87f3ff04063800aec256c3d4b4be/library/core/src/panicking.rs:67:14
   2: ash::extensions_generated::khr::wayland_surface::InstanceFn::load_erased::create_wayland_surface_khr
             at /home/lazerpie/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/ash-0.38.0+1.3.281/src/extensions_generated.rs:10495:29
   3: ash::extensions::khr::wayland_surface::<impl ash::extensions_generated::khr::wayland_surface::Instance>::create_wayland_surface
             at /home/lazerpie/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/ash-0.38.0+1.3.281/src/extensions/khr/wayland_surface.rs:17:9
   4: render_test::main
             at ./src/main.rs:809:42
   5: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/5680fa18feaa87f3ff04063800aec256c3d4b4be/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.

why am I getting this error?
I haven't really tried anything, as I haven't been able to find anything on this type of error. Though, earlier, I got the same error when trying to use
let display_khr: Vec<vk::DisplayKHR> = unsafe{display_instance.get_display_plane_supported_displays(physical_device, 0u32)}.expect("failed to get displayKHR");

the error:
thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to load create_wayland_surface_khr'

turns out I needed to enable the extensions VK_KHR_surface and VK_KHR_wayland_surface
